# Using Ajax result with window.open c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, character-encoding

Firstly I used something like this;

> window.open('@Url.TemplateUrl("ControllerPath")', '_blank');

That works for me, but I wanted to pass my Javascript variable to controller and I tried something like this;

```
var loginWindow = window.open('', 'UserLogin');

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET', url: '@Url.TemplateUrl("ControllerPath")', data: ({ index: number }),
                traditional: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    loginWindow.document.body.innerHTML = result;
                },
                error: function () {alert('error') }
            });
```

But my html comes corrupted whereas the first attempt was perfectly fine.

What can i do? Please help me

Comment: Can you tell us what the corrupt HTML was?

Comment: And what was your first attempt? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: My first attempt was just writing

window.open('@Url.TemplateUrl("ControllerPath")', '_blank');

Comment: corrput html was something like this more or less
%PDF-1.4 %���� 1 0 obj <>stream x��X}LUewQ�F�ݒ�)��C)�4(%�3�&�y��b��2��SK&���T|��j��{S��$�fB�-���lI|<�s��>��9��n��q��y��y~����=�s�s8<2;�����1��*4�ʈ u�-�B�Iz�{W���b�s�3�o������!<#I]���ZT�}/K���-���Ũ�$v{��Zq��u�R#��i��?�x�Z�x!n�%������r����:�.�jmϔ7R$��b9S�3�%�,�^R>���h,�����Bx��-��"23���fo{o�v�n%�@�,�y-�`_$�XB �X�"r�g��_5Z��Ӯ�H�Y=�6��y�fū�3�va;���o��||��8�� ����\.�Q������KZ��l��܄�#<���'F�sP/vjD����:��'98,������i���PB +�9�LpP�Ј����w���J3G��*s�q:�~D*�C�.�֮vLZ�X�/I���

Comment: And lastly controller returns (FileContentResult Controller.File)

Comment: That looks like a corrupted PDF. The likely corruption is probably due to an incorrect character encoding, or using a character encoding for binary data.

Comment: but my first attempt works fine, how is that possible :(